# Access - Table event issue

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-data-macro

I'm new to Access 2010 and I have a issue with creating an `After Insert` Table event in my Access Database.

I want it such that after the insertion of a new row in table `example`, a new record will be created in table `table2` with the `jobid` data.

I have created a example database with my event in After insert table which is not working:

[image: macro]

Answer (score 1):

You can create *after insert event* on *example* table as follow
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kffS0.jpg

This will be work if you insert a new record in example

```
If  Updated("PaidInFull")   Then 

/* Perform actions based on changes to the field.   */ 

End If
```

For more information refer to the [documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196099.aspx).